# Android horizontal custom gallery - 3rd party library or native?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, coverflow

I'm afraid, I'm not very able to name what I'm trying to achieve, so this is library providing similar functionality in jQuery.

Is there any library or native way, how to achieve this kind of effect, with custom views?
Like music library does for browsing album covers, or OS X browsing through folder (Cover Flow)

[image: Similar in jQuery]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No native way. Search for libraries or write it on your own.

Best way to use [RenderScript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html) or [OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html)

Also see [Android 3D Carousel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel) tutorial.